# Responsive checkerboard pattern background

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

I want to have a responsive checkerboard background that should look like the background in a color selector:

[image: Wanted result]

I want the pattern to always show ***N*** number of squares-per-width (dynamic).

#### What I tried:

```css
.chess {
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(90deg, #999 30px, white 30px), 
    linear-gradient(90deg, white 30px, #999 30px), 
    linear-gradient(90deg, #999 30px, white 30px), 
    linear-gradient(90deg, white 30px, #999 30px), 
    linear-gradient(90deg, #999 30px, white 30px), 
    linear-gradient(90deg, white 30px, #999 30px), 
    linear-gradient(90deg, #999 30px, white 30px);
  background-position: 0 0, 0 30px, 0 60px, 0 90px, 0 120px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 60px 30px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 30%;
}


.fas {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10em
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary chess">
  <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
  </div>
<div>
```

The squares are not 1:1 aspect ratio if the container isn't also, and that is not responsive:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  resize: auto;
  overflow: hidden;

  aspect-ratio: 1/2;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: repeating-conic-gradient(transparent 0 90deg, grey 0 180deg) 
              0 0 / 25% 25% round;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Problems:**

- My result is not responsive. (I have fixed pixel sizes)
- I would need a lot of code if I have a larger background or smaller elements.
- I was unable to center the pattern or use [`background-repeat: round`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-repeat/)

If it is possible, I do not want any cut-offs in the checkerboard background.

Not like this (cut off on the right and bottom):

[image]

Comment: It certainly won't be responsive if you use **fixed pixel values**...I'd start there.

Comment: you want the elements to be centered?

Comment: If its possible i want their size adjusted to the parent size so they are not cut off. But the idea of centering the checkerboard background sounds good too!

Comment: have you tried to use flex on it? display:flex; justify-content:center;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an idea that rely on [conic-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/conic-gradient):

```css
.chess {
  background:
    repeating-conic-gradient(
        #fff 0 90deg,
        grey 0 180deg) 
    0 0/25% 25%;
  margin: 15px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="chess fas fa-7x fa-car"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-5x fa-car"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-10x fa-user"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-3x fa-phone"></div>
```

[image: CSS responsive checkerboard]

You can also consider `round` of `background-repeat` if you want to have the same size and no cut off:

```css
.chess {
  background:
    repeating-conic-gradient(
        #fff 0 90deg,
        grey 0 180deg) 
    0 0/40px 40px round;
  margin: 15px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="chess fas fa-7x fa-car"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-5x fa-car"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-10x fa-user"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-3x fa-phone"></div>
```

[image: CSS chessboard reasponsive]

---

For better support, you can replace the gradient with an SVG to have the same result:

```css
.chess {
  background:
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect x="0" y="0" width="5" height="5" fill="grey" /><rect x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5" fill="grey" /><rect x="5" y="0" width="5" height="5" fill="white" /><rect x="0" y="5" width="5" height="5" fill="white" /></svg>') 
    0 0/25% 25%;
  margin: 15px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="chess fas fa-7x fa-car"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-5x fa-car"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-10x fa-user"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-3x fa-phone"></div>
```

And with a fixed size:

```css
.chess {
  background:
    url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg preserveAspectRatio="none"  viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect x="0" y="0" width="5" height="5" fill="grey" /><rect x="5" y="5" width="5" height="5" fill="grey" /><rect x="5" y="0" width="5" height="5" fill="white" /><rect x="0" y="5" width="5" height="5" fill="white" /></svg>') 
    0 0/40px 40px round;
  margin: 15px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="chess fas fa-7x fa-car"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-5x fa-car"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-10x fa-user"></div>
<div class="chess fas fa-3x fa-phone"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Temani - If the area (of the background) is not 1:1 (aspect ratio) then the squares size won't look good when responsive (not absolute units like pixels) [see demo](https://jsbin.com/huzizoy/edit?html,css,output), you know of a trick to keep the squares responsive (constant **N** squares per width)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little trick to create a **responsive** pattern (fixed amount of repeated graphics for any possible width).

Since CSS does not (as of writing this) supports width/height sizing relative to parent width/height, it leaves no choice but to create an extra (pseudo) element and multiply it's size drastically, relative to its container, while maintaining aspect-ratio of a perfect square `1:1`.

With some simple math, it is then possible to easily control the amounts of repeats we wish the pattern to appear at, which is `10` at the below example. Mind, it is a **resizable** example:

```css
div {
  width: 60%;
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: auto;
  position: relative;
  outline: 2px dashed salmon;
}

div::before {
  --pattern-repeated: 10; /* squares per-row */
  --pattern-color-1: transparent;
  --pattern-color-2: PaleGreen;
  
  content: 'Resize me';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  /* a huge width is used to make sure the there's plenty of rows */
  width: 10000%;  

  /* make the pattern way bigger than its container */
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;  
  
  background:
    repeating-conic-gradient(
        var(--pattern-color-1) 0 90deg,
        var(--pattern-color-2) 0 180deg) 
    0 0 /
    
    /* for every 0 past the third from left devide by 100 by 10, so 10,000% has 3 extra zeros
     * 100 / 10 / 10 = 1 and since "conic-gradient" means 4 squares (2 up, 2 down) per repeated patten, 
     * need double the pattern's size should be doubled manually so the exact number of "--pattern-repeated"
     * columns would render, so 1% becomes 2%, which results in 10 columns in this demo.
     */
    calc(2%/var(--pattern-repeated)) calc(2%/var(--pattern-repeated)) round;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```css
.chess {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc 25%, transparent 25%),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, #ccc 25%, transparent 25%),
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #ccc 75%),
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #ccc 75%);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 29px, 29px -29px, -29px 0px;
}
.btn {}

.fas {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10em;
}


.fas.f5em {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.fas.f35em {
  font-size: 35em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.7.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary chess">
  <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
  </div>
<div>

<div>
  <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary chess">
  <i class="fas fa-car f5em"></i>
  </div>
<div>

<div>
  <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary chess">
  <i class="fas fa-car f35em"></i>
  </div>
<div>
```

OR you can use pattern image like:

```
https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5705/alpha.png
```