# How can even rows will be shifted while using background-image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use `background-image` to create a div using this code:

```css
square {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1000px;
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="40"><image width="40" height="40" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAFVJREFUeNrs2EENgEAQBMGBoOOsgLQTgaB1dV9Cggf2Ua2g3r2te5xJrvSsjg83mwLnnuYBAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC/tV7+St9L389AgwA9YgGfH7VrXwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" /></svg>');
        background-repeat: repeat;
      }
```

But I got a block of vertical lines aligned. I want to shift the even rows by some pixels to the right and not having all the lines aligned vertically.
I tried this code:

```css
 .square:nth-child(even) {
        background-size: 10px right;
      }
```

But it does not works. Is there any solution to fix that?

```css
  .square {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 1000px;
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="40"><image width="40" height="40" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAFVJREFUeNrs2EENgEAQBMGBoOOsgLQTgaB1dV9Cggf2Ua2g3r2te5xJrvSsjg83mwLnnuYBAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC/tV7+St9L389AgwA9YgGfH7VrXwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" /></svg>');
        background-repeat: repeat;
      }
      
      .square:nth-child(even) {
        background-size: 10px right;
      }
```

```html
 <div class="square">
    </div>
```

Updated:

I tried to create a pattern similar to checkboard pattern using this:

```css
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
   margin:0;

    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="40"><image width="40" height="40" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAFVJREFUeNrs2EENgEAQBMGBoOOsgLQTgaB1dV9Cggf2Ua2g3r2te5xJrvSsjg83mwLnnuYBAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC/tV7+St9L389AgwA9YgGfH7VrXwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" /></svg>'), url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="40"><image width="40" height="40" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAFVJREFUeNrs2EENgEAQBMGBoOOsgLQTgaB1dV9Cggf2Ua2g3r2te5xJrvSsjg83mwLnnuYBAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC/tV7+St9L389AgwA9YgGfH7VrXwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" /></svg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  left 40px top, left 40px
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
</div>
```

However, when I set the `background-repeat: repeat` the result is not what I'm looking for:

```css
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
   margin:0;

    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="40"><image width="40" height="40" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAFVJREFUeNrs2EENgEAQBMGBoOOsgLQTgaB1dV9Cggf2Ua2g3r2te5xJrvSsjg83mwLnnuYBAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC/tV7+St9L389AgwA9YgGfH7VrXwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" /></svg>'), url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height="40"><image width="40" height="40" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAFVJREFUeNrs2EENgEAQBMGBoOOsgLQTgaB1dV9Cggf2Ua2g3r2te5xJrvSsjg83mwLnnuYBAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIC/tV7+St9L389AgwA9YgGfH7VrXwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" /></svg>');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position:  left 40px top, left 40px
}
```

```html
<div class='container'></div>
```

Comment: you want a checkboard pattern?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55455760/8620333

Comment: You only have one div in your example so unsure how you expect the css rule to apply to it.

Comment: Seems like you could just have your SVG be two squares so when it is repeated it makes the pattern.

Comment: @epascarello can you explain more your idea please?

Comment: So you make an SVG with two rows in a checker board pattern and that will be what you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif I tried to make something similar to checkboard pattern but I think that I miss something in the code. The issue that in my situation the `orange` square will be changed by a custom svg and it's not a color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mask to do this:

```css
.container {
  --size: 50px; /* the size of the pattern*/

  height: 100vh;
  background: 
   url(https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/300) /* your custom SVG here */
   0 0/var(--size) var(--size);
  -webkit-mask: 
   repeating-conic-gradient(#0000 0 25%,#000 0 50%)
   0 0/calc(2*var(--size)) calc(2*var(--size));
}


body {
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'></div>
```